# Un "estuario bituminoso" è una foce contaminata?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Tempesta solare*  di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> La rotta è sicura, il mare è calmo, domani saremo in vista delle familiari coste del Galles, tra due giorni imboccheremo *l'estuario
>   bituminoso* della Mersey, getteremo l'ancora nel porto di Liverpool, termine del viaggio.

Ho cercato il significato di "bituminoso" in alcuni dizionari. Comunque non capisco cosa intenda dire l'autore con  "estuario bituminoso". Si riferisce al fatto che la foce del fiume è contaminata?

Comment: Probabilmente è un riferimento agli scarichi delle navi che rendono l'acqua nei porti *oleosa*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La Mersey era uno dei fiumi europei più inquinati fino agli anni '80, quando fu finalmente ripulito con successo. Fin dalla seconda metà del 1700 l'area ha visto un enorme aumento in popolazione con la crescita industriale di Manchester e del porto di Liverpool. Negli anni '60 non solo l'area diventò enormemente industrializzata (era anche il luogo di maggior sviluppo dell'industria chimica) rilasciando nel fiume ogni sorta di rifiuto, ma anche le fognature, che servivano una popolazione di 5 milioni di persone, finivano nella Mersey. A Liverpool c'era il detto che non si potesse annegare nella Mersey, si sarebbe morti avvelenati prima.
In più l'estuario della Mersey ha una notevole variazione di livello dovuta alla marea, che alza parecchio sedimento, da foto del "Mascheretto" puoi notare come l'acqua appaia "densa" e grigioscura.
La definizione di "bituminoso" può riferirsi ad una delle due cose o ad entrambe.

Comment: Grazie per l'edit, con una tastiera inglese aggiungere gli accenti come si deve diventa difficile quindi per abitudine uso gli apostrofi

Answer (score 1):

Riferendosi ad un fiume e ad una zona notoriamente inquinati a causa degli scarichi industriali di varia natura, "bituminoso" molto probabilmente si riferisce all'inquinamento visibile delle acque del fiume:

***[Bitume](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/B/bitume.php):***

> - ***Sostanza infiammabile, untuosa, liquida e giallastra*** o nera e solida, formata da una miscela di idrocarburi, ***estratta da giacimenti naturali oppure ricavata da rocce asfaltiche o dai residui della distillazione del petrolio, usata per pavimentare le strade, per opere di impermeabilizzazione in edilizia e per vernici***

***[Bituminoso](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/B/bituminoso.php):***

agg.

> - Che contiene o produce bitume
>     || estens. Che ha l'aspetto, il colore del bitume